# com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserToken(android.accounts.AccountManager.getAuthToken(???))

Tags: java, android, authentication, gdata

I've got working code that uses the gdata to retrieve feeds from my user's Google Finance portfolios, but I had to use *setUserCredentials(username,password)*. What I'd like to do is avoid asking the user for their username/password since the Android device already has access to their Google account.

I believe I should be able to do this with *setUserToken(String)*, but I can't figure out how to get the appropriate token from Android. I've tried *AccountManager.get(context).blockingGetAuthToken()* but that's either not the correct call or I'm passing it the wrong arguments.

Has anyone gotten gdata working with the user's existing Google credentials on the phone?

Thanks in advance,
Lenny

Comment: I suspect that you forgot to put USE_CREDENTIALS permission in your manifest file?

Comment: It was in the manifest when I first tested, and android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS is also in the manifest file.

Comment: did you by any chance ever find an answer to this question? I would be very interested!

Answer (score 0):

`AccountManager.blockingGetAuthToken()` is the correct call.  Pass it an `Account`, and an `String authTokenType` -- In your case, `"android"` or `"finance"`, your pick (the values of the strings it's looking for are not clearly documented).

The easy way to obtain an account is to do all your client comms as part of the `onPerformSync()` call on a class that implmenents a Sync Adapter.  You can find a number of tutorials on getting a SyncAdapter set up.  As part of getting your SyncAdapter going, you'll end up with a mess of permissions, probably like the following or so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.finance" />
```

Those last two, again, sort of tricksy, dug them out of who knows where.