# Pulling data from Google Calendar on Android in JSON

Tags: android, json, gdata

I'm using Android SDK level 8, Java. I have an app with a WebView and I want to import JSON in it.

What I want to achieve is:
Send HTTP requests to the [Google Calendar API v3](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/) and receive data in raw JSON, however, authenticating the request using the Android account manager. I've been looking at the GData Java Client, more specifically at the [Calendar Android Sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default), which authenticates properly, but I want to specifically avoid the following things:

- Using the GData API - unacceptable since I want a raw JSON string.
- Pulling the data directly through JavaScript in the WebView - unacceptable since I would want to implement a SyncProvider in Java to update the JSON string

I found some information about the issue, for example:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/AndroidAccountManager

[com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserToken(android.accounts.AccountManager.getAuthToken(???))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025985/com-google-gdata-client-googleservice-setusertokenandroid-accounts-accountmanag)

However, all the examples are connected with GData. On the other hand, exploring the Google Calendar v3 API page, I could not figure out how to authenticate with an auth token from the Account Manager.

In summation: how to retrieve JSON through plain HTTP requests to the Calendar API v3, authenticating the user with the token from the account manager, in Java.